# Loading .csv file into R Studio with GPS values

Tags: r, gps, data-import

I'm trying to load a climate .csv file into R. All the data appears in the first column.
There are no error message but everything I tried doesn't work.

Here's what I've  tried :

```r
rouyn2005 <- read.csv('historique_rouyn_2005_03.csv', header=TRUE, sep=',')
rouyn2005 <-read.csv('historique_rouyn_2005_03.csv', header=TRUE, sep=';')
```

I also tried the steps with the 'reader' package with no success.

I would like to join the .csv file but I don't know how to.

I'll show the column names and the first line of the file.

**Column names**
Longitude (x),"Latitude (y)","Nom de la Station","ID climatologique","Date/Heure","Année","Mois","Jour","Qualité des Données","Temp max.(°C)","Temp max. Indicateur","Temp min.(°C)","Temp min. Indicateur","Temp moy.(°C)","Temp moy. Indicateur","DJC (°C)","DJC Indicateur","DJR (°C)","DJR Indicateur","Pluie tot. (mm)","Pluie tot. Indicateur","Neige tot. (cm)","Neige tot. Indicateur","Précip. tot. (mm)","Précip. tot. Indicateur","Neige au sol (cm)","Neige au sol Indicateur","Dir. raf. max. (10s deg)","Dir. raf. max. Indicateur","Vit. raf. max. (km/h)","Vit. raf. max. Indicateur"

**First line values**
-79,03,"48,25","ROUYN","7086716","2005-01-03","2005","01","03","","-6,2","","-22,2","","-14,2","","32,2","","0,0","","","M","","M","0,0","","","","33","","37",""

RStudio Version 1.4.1717.Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 12_4_0

Comment: If there are no error messages, it should have worked. What happens if you simply run `rouyn2005` in the console?

Comment: Is your `-79,03` actually unquoted, i.e. not `"-79,03"`?

Comment: @AndreaM here's what happens:   -79,03,"48,25","ROUYN","7086716","2005-01-01","2005","01","01","","-11,5","","-24,2","","-17,9","","35,9","","0,0","","","M","","M","0,0","","","","30","","46",""

Comment: @jay.sf, I noticed that. The governement files I got are all set that way and I don't know why. I think it should be quoted.

Comment: @Christophe, so it worked: that command imported the data. It seems like the issue is not in your code but in the original dataset.

Comment: @AndreaM, ok. That's what I thought. They indicate how to import it in excel, but not in any other software. Is there any way I can resolve the issue in the original dataset?

Comment: @Christophe, I suspect the issue is that the first value is unquoted. Try fixing that manually in notepad and see if that helps when you import into R

Comment: @AndreaM the thing is I got thousands of rows to analyse. Not very realistic to change all of them manually!

Comment: @gaut I got this error message : > dat <- fread('historique_rouyn_2005_03.csv')
Warning message:
In fread("historique_rouyn_2005_03.csv") :
  Found and resolved improper quoting in first 100 rows. If the fields are not quoted (e.g. field separator does not appear within any field), try quote="" to avoid this warning.

Comment: @gaut. Then: 
> dat <- fread('historique_rouyn_2005_03.csv', quote="")
Warning messages:
1: In fread("historique_rouyn_2005_03.csv", quote = "") :
  Detected 31 column names but the data has 39 columns (i.e. invalid file). Added 8 extra default column names at the end.
2: In fread("historique_rouyn_2005_03.csv", quote = "") :
  Stopped early on line 76. Expected 39 fields but found 38. Consider fill=TRUE and comment.char=. First discarded non-empty line: <<"-79,03,""48,25"",""ROUYN"",""7086716"",""2005-03-16"",""2005"",""03"",""16"","""",""-6,6"","""",""-10,9"","""","">>

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `fread` from `data.table`?

```
install.packages('data.table')
library(data.table)
dat <- fread('historique_rouyn_2005_03.csv')
```